# Installing OpenSceneGraph Visual 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, openscenegraph

I have some trouble installing OpenSceneGraph with Visual Studio 2015.

I followed this old tutorial : [How to build OpenSceneGraph from source and third party dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779029/how-to-build-openscenegraph-from-source-and-third-party-dependencies) and it fails at some point

Here is what I've done so far :

- Download OSG 3.4 from this link : https://github.com/openscenegraph/OpenSceneGraph/tree/OpenSceneGraph-3.4.0
- Build with CMake (I am not sure here, I set the compiler to Visual Studio 14 2015 Win 64, I haven't try with just Visual Studio 14 2015)
- Build ALL_BUILD, after that I had a lot of warning : `declaration of 'xxx' hides previous local declaration`

And then when I try to build INSTALL it fails after this error :

```
Error   MSB3073 The command "setlocal
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Debug -P cmake_install.cmake
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd
:cmEnd
endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone
:cmErrorLevel
exit /b %1
:cmDone
if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd
:VCEnd" exited with code 1. INSTALL C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  133
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is asking for admin rights to install. Change the location in CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX in the CMake GUI.